# Mobile Phones - Using JavaScript to make snapshots via phone camera

Tags: javascript

some months ago I developed a special php web application for mobile phones.
Our customers use Samsung Galaxy xcover with Android and Opera Mobile for browsing the application.

Inside my web application I use a client-side JavaScript functionality called "navigator.getUserMedia", which is supported by Opera Mobile. I think it's very powerful, but there's something I'm missing.

Look: I use "navigator.getUserMedia" to give the user the possibility to make camera snapshots and upload the images to my webserver directory via Ajax (I think so).

And it works fine, really!

But - and that's my problem - I haven't found out how to change resolution of these phone snapshots.
The main problem is that the captured images are too small (144px x 144px).

I checked the whole JavaScript code if there are rules or definitions which possibly control the created images' size. I found some width- and height-definitions (in px) and I changed them to see what would happen. But I had no luck. The created images' size is still 144px x 144px :-(

Now I'm not sure if it's generally a JS problem.
Could it be that the "navigator.getUserMedia" functionality doesn't have the possibilities I need?

Is anybody there who had or has the same problem?
Did anybody solve it?

Yours

Donny

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but maybe you can check the "Resize the video" section in [MDN tutorial on "Taking webcam photos"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/taking_webcam_photos).

Comment: Hi, 
 
thanx for your help. You were right - it was the hyperlink which offers the solution.

The code I needed is:
 
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
 
It is not hard to use it but it was hard to find.
I wonder that I'm the only one who searched for it.
 
Thanks again.

Donny